# Complex number field: ''essentially'' unique?

Tags: complex-analysis, field-theory, definition

I solved the following exercise but have trouble making sense of the result:

If $\widetilde{\mathbb C}$ is another field of complex numbers and $\varphi : \mathbb C \to \widetilde{\mathbb C}$ is a ring homomorphism fixing the real numebrs then it follows that $\varphi$  is bijective and therefore the field of complex numbers is essentially uniquely determined.

I had no trouble showing that $\varphi$ is bijective: it follows directly from the fact that it is a ring homomorphism and that for $x \in \mathbb R$ we have $\varphi (x) = x$.

But I have trouble understanding what it  means that then the complex numbers are ''essentially uniquely determined''.

> Please could someone explain to me what this means?

It seems to me that even though any homomorphism fixing the reals turns out to be bijective we could still find a field of complex numbers such that there is no $\varphi : \mathbb C \to \widetilde{\mathbb C}$ that preserves $\mathbb R$ or maybe even no homomorphism $\varphi$ at all. Then wouldn't this mean that the complex numbers are not unique?

**Edit**

In the (complex analysis) book there is a theorem which states that there exists a field $\mathbb C$ that

(1) Contains $\mathbb R$ as a subfield

(2) has a solution to $x^2 + 1$

(3) if $i$ denotes one of these solutions then the map $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$, $(x,y) \mapsto x + iy$ is bijective.

**Edit 2**

I believe there should be an answer without using ''algebraicity'' because it is not mentioned in the book which is a book about complex analysis and ''algebraicity'' is an algebraic property. I believe it should be possible to explain this using only basic complex analysis since it's an exercise in the first chapter of the book.

Comment: When you say that $\tilde{\mathbb{C}}$ is "a field of complex numbers," do you mean that it contains a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and has an element $x\in \mathbb{\tilde{C}}$ such that $x^2+1=0$?

Comment: @Andrew: That condition isn't sufficient for the conclusion to hold. For example, $\tilde{\mathbb C}$ might be $\mathbb C$ with more-than-continuum-many new transcendentals adjoined, but then $\varphi$ certainly cannot be a bijection.

Comment: @Andrew Yes. ....

Comment: (Actually, adjoining a single transcendental is enough; we get the fraction field of $\mathbb C[X]$ which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ because it isn't algebraically closed).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Then the field of complex numbers is not ''essentially uniquely determined'', right?

Comment: @Anna There is only one *algebraic* extension of $\Bbb R$ with a $\sqrt{-1}$ up to isomorphism. This avoids the problem with adding transcendental elements that Henning mentions.

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't understand your comment. Also, ''algebraic'' is never mentioned in the exercise.

Comment: Condition (3) implies algebraicity.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't understand why algebraicity helps and also why there cannot be a construction like Henning suggests. This is all very confusing.  I also don't understand the answer which talks about automorphisms when the question is about maps from $\mathbb C$ to $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ (therefore not automorphisms).

Comment: The construction that Henning gives cannot satisfy (3).

Comment: I still don't understand how the uniqueness follows from the fact that only the homomorphisms that preserve the real numbers are bijective.

Comment: @Anna: The _meaning_ of the phrase "uniquely determined" in this context is that any two "fields of complex numbers" are isomorphic, nothing more. If you can prove that the map in question always exists and always is bijective, then it will be an isomorphism, and you have proved that every "field of complex numbers" is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ -- an thus all such field are isomorphic to each other; in other words "uniquely determined".

Comment: Thank you @HenningMakholm I now understand. The problem was with how the exercise was phrased.

Answer (score 0):

The existence of a ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb C\to\tilde{\mathbb C}$ that preserves $\mathbb R$ can be easily proved by simply constructing it.

According to property (3), the map $\mu:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb C, (x,y)\mapsto x+iy$ is bijective, and so is $\tilde\mu:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\tilde{\mathbb C}, (x,y)\mapsto x+\tilde iy$, where $\tilde i$ denotes a solution of $x^2+1=0$ in $\tilde{\mathbb C}$. Therefore $\phi:=\tilde\mu\circ\mu^{-1}$ is a bijection $\mathbb C\to\tilde{\mathbb C}$. In particular, it maps $x+iy$ to $x+\tilde i y$.

Now it is easy to check that $\phi$ is indeed a ring homomorphism, and that it preserves $\mathbb R$.

Comment: This 4 years later answer does not adress the question, which was about the "essential uniqueness" of this field.